# Phonegap Ionic app not working from device with rest API

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Now I'm trying to make login call to express rest API with passport Basic Strategy, and on browser everything working fine but from device from Phonegap it's not working. I tried to remove and add cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin. Added following tag to config.xml `<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />`. And added to index.html `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">` I made cors setup. But it didn't help. Also I found out that my requests contains "/proxy/" inside of call.

Here is example: `http://192.168.1.189:3000/proxy/http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8080%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Flogin`

is it ok? And here is what I'm getting from server:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some time for search and I found a solution:
In my ionic app.js file I just changed the following line:

```
const BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api';
```

to:

```
const BASE_URL = 'http://192.168.1.102:8080/api';
```

and it works for me.